# excel how to search content text from multiple that opening file

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have one folder that content many excel file in it(share drive). file opening by user using it. How we can search text in each file. I trying search by ''content:"str search"'' but result show from only file that close.

any help please. thank in advance.

Comment: Did you search content in Folder Search box?

Comment: yes i search it